# How to find the % difference between values on 2 rows in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find the difference between the current value and the previous value and display the table as a % difference between them.

The code to find the difference between the 2 consecutive rows was:

```
abcfin <- abcfin %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list( ~ . - lag(.)))
```

The code that I have used to get the result is:

```
asdfg <- abcfin %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(ifelse(lag(.)!=0,(. - lag(.))*100/ lag(.)), 0))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Error in `-.Date`(left, right) : can only subtract from "Date" objects
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  :
>     data length [5974] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [543]

Kindly let me know the right code statement that I can use to obtain the required results:

[image]

Comment: There is a `~` missing in the second expression `abcfin %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ ifelse(lag(.)!=0,(. - lag(.))*100/ lag(.)), 0))`

Comment: I am getting an error saying:
Error: not expecting this
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: As @IceCreamToucan mentioned in the comments, please check the brackets of `ifelse`

Comment: Yeah should be `mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ ifelse(lag(.) != 0, (. - lag(.)) * 100 / lag(.), 0)))`. The `0` was not inside the `ifelse` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way that might be easier to follow if you're new to R:

```
library(tidyverse)

date <- seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 6)
var1 <- c(723, 983, 437, 732, 173, 537)
var2 <- c(753, 769, 352, 853, 143, 485)
df <- data.frame(date, var1, var2) 
df <- df %>% mutate(var1_prev = lag(var1), var2_prev = lag(var2))

df <- df[-1,] #removes unnecessary first row
df <- df %>% mutate(var1_perdiff = (var1 - var1_prev)/var1_prev * 100,
                    var2_perdiff = (var2 - var2_prev)/var2_prev * 100)

as_tibble(df)
# A tibble: 5 x 7
#date        var1  var2 var1_prev var2_prev var1_perdiff var2_perdiff
#<date>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 2015-02-01   983   769       723       753         36.0         2.12
#2 2015-03-01   437   352       983       769        -55.5       -54.2 
#3 2015-04-01   732   853       437       352         67.5       142.  
#4 2015-05-01   173   143       732       853        -76.4       -83.2 
#5 2015-06-01   537   485       173       143        210.        239.
```

Comment: Thanks! that is easy to understand!

Comment: great! could you please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

data.table solution:

```
# set to data.table
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)

# your percentage function
perct.fun <- function(x){-100 + (x/shift(x,1,type = "lag"))*100}

# add the new variables
v <- c("var1","var2")
df[order(date), (paste0(v, "_diff")) := lapply(.SD, perct.fun), .SDcols=v]

         date var1 var2 var1_diff  var2_diff
1: 2015-01-01  723  753        NA         NA
2: 2015-02-01  983  769  35.96127   2.124834
3: 2015-03-01  437  352 -55.54425 -54.226268
4: 2015-04-01  732  853  67.50572 142.329545
5: 2015-05-01  173  143 -76.36612 -83.235639
6: 2015-06-01  537  485 210.40462 239.160839
```